# Jersey client calling RESTful service

Tags: java, rest, authentication, jersey, client

I am new to using Jersey and I am struggling to get my client working against an existing RESTful service.  I have a SOAPUI call that works, here is the raw data from that request.

```
POST http://localhost/QWJB/WENXrest//getHistory HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Content-Length: 189
Authorization: Basic VUNRRzE02fr45tDE0d1RQdw==
Host: localhost

{getHistory:       
{
wENXHeader:
{
languageCode: "en"
},

Account: "111111111",

    services: 
    [
        {Service: "CE000001"},
        {Service: "CE000002"}
    ]
    }

}
```

At this point I am willing to hard code all the values in just to see it work.  But here is my client code.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public void MakeRestCall() {
  try {
GetHistory requestData = new GetHistory();
requestData.setAccount("111111111");

Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client
.resource("http://localhost/QWJB/WNEXrest//getHistory");

webResource.accept("application/json");
webResource.entity(requestData);

GetHistoryResponse response =       
webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(GetHistoryResponse.class);

} catch (Exception e) {
logger.error(message);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I use SOAPUI I have to set a userid and password, is that what is in the authorization part of the raw request?  What should I use to encrypt it?

Comment: Juned's answer helped me solve the issue.  I also had to have all of my webresource calls on the same line, the way I was doing it I was only setting the last line in my header webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(GetHistoryResponse.class)

Answer (score 3):

**Framing Authentication Header**

As your REST service is using Basic authentication, so you can set the jersey rest client authentication using this:

```
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
```